# Is there a way to determine whether a file can be opened as a System.IO.Packaging.Package?

Tags: c#, .net, file, stream, system.io.packaging

If I have a filepath or stream, is there a static method I can use to determine whether the file/stream is a package, other than by trying to use `Package.Open` on the file/stream and catching the `System.IO.FileFormatException`?

Comment: Not that I can see; and stepping through the reference source down about 10 levels, suggests that there would be no work saved in writing one. I could not even find the throw of **FileFormatException** in about 20 minutes searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either attempt to open the file as a .zip file and then look for metadata (thus implementing part of the package specification where you verify the package format) or you can just use `Open()` and catch any potential exception. (The .docx / .xlsx / etc. formats are just ZIP files that follow a certain structure.)

You can try reading the ZIP header but that will only verify that the file is a ZIP file - I'm not sure this buys you much (if anything).

My guess is that trying to open the file and catching the exception is the easiest route to go - if the specification changes your code will keep working. If you roll your own code to verify the file format, you'll have to keep maintaining it.